# How to set same appearance for dynamically created custom listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I'm getting problem in setting equal width space for elements of dynamically created custom listview in Fragment. All the elements are arranged in same listview. Please give a idea to how to make it all unique in custom view.Please see this image. Help me. Thanks in advance!!!!

[Screeshort of my design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyW99.png)

Code ------>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#800080"
        android:id="@+id/txt1">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#800080"
        android:id="@+id/txt2">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#800080"
        android:id="@+id/txt3">
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/del_button"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="addItems"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:theme="@style/MyButton"/>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better idea to use GridView. You did not provide ListView`s code but I think TableLayot and TableRow is useless. But anyways you can try to put the TextViews and Button in LinearLayout and give them some weights. 
Fore example, to give them equal space:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#800080"
    android:id="@+id/txt1">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#800080"
    android:id="@+id/txt2">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#800080"
    android:id="@+id/txt3">
</TextView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/del_button"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="addItems"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:theme="@style/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use TableRow.LayoutParams [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: This weightsum has increased space between tow listview but i need to make equal space between elements of single listview..